# Valgrind reporting invalid read on one system but not another

Tags: c++, c, segmentation-fault, valgrind

I need to run a rather large software package on a new machine for work.  The application is written in C and C++ and I am running on CentOS 6.5.

The program builds fine, but segfaults when I go to run it.  Using valgrind, I see the following error reported at the location of the segfault:

```
==23843== Invalid read of size 4
[stack trace here]
==23843==  Address 0x642e7464 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

So for some reason we are reading from memory we aren't supposed to and are invoking undefined behaviour.  When I tar up my source files, take them to another CentOS 6.5 machine (w/ same kernel) and compile them (with same makefiles and same GCC version) the program seems to run fine.

I ran valgrind on that machine as well and expected to see the invalid read again.  My thought was that the invalid read would always be present, yet because the behaviour is undefined things just happened to work correctly on one machine and not on the other.

What I found, however, was that valgrind reports no read errors on the second machine.  How could this be possible?

Comment: And then I am supposed to guess what caused it? where is the code?

Comment: I am just looking for explanation of how an invalid read could manifest on computer but not another.  My perception was that the invalid read would always be present, and the behaviour resulting from the invalid read is what could vary.

Comment: I edited the question to specify that the compiler version is the same

Comment: It looks like the address is a random value, so it might point to readable memory by accident in some circumstances, and not in others.

Comment: The address interpreted as ASCII spells out `"d.td"` (MSB first). No idea if that means anything to you, but often when ASCII text appears in addresses, that can help to a) identify the issue as an overwrite and b) help identify the source.

Comment: A great number of things could cause the program to follow an execution path different enough in one environment than it is in the other to result in the invalid read occuring only in one context.  Different hardware, different library or compiler versions, different compilation options, different time of day, different working directory, different user name, different program arguments, and many, many more differences could have an effect.  Without any code, we have no chance of narrowing it down.

Comment: Check the version of libraries used on both systems.

Comment: What version of Valgrind are you using.  I used an older version which complained about `Invalid read of size 1` from strlen (another function called strlen, not my program).  The solution was to update my Valgrind.  Then the error disappeared.  Make sure you are running the same version of Vagrind on both systems.

Comment: Are you sure you running the exact same test cases on both machines? That is the program takes the exact same execution path?

Comment: There is a bug in the source. Feel lucky you at least have **one** machine pointing you to this. Fix the bug on this latter machine and be happy.

Answer (score 3):

Valgrind makes the running environment more deterministic, but it does not eliminate all randomness. Maybe the other machine has bit different versions of libraries installed, or anything external it is using (files, network..) is different, the code execution does not have to be exactly the same.

You should look at the stack trace and analyze the code where the error happens. If it is not obvious from the stack trace alone, you can start `valgrind` with `--vgdb=full` parameter. It will pause the execution once the error happens and print out instructions how to attach `gdb`. Or you can just run the program under debugger directly - you wrote that it crashes even without valgrind.

Answer (score 0):

Different library versions are the best guess, judging from the sparse information you gave. Things to try:

1) Bring both machines up to date via package manager and try again

2) Run `ldd [binary]` to see all libraries used by the program in question. Run something like `md5sum` on them on both machines to find out if there are differences.

In general I made the experience that valgrind is really bad at detecting invalid memory access on the stack, so this might be a hidden root cause. If all else fails, you might want to try using clang and address sanitizer. It might find things valgrind doesn't catch, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by using different versions of Valgrind.

Some common false positive errors get removed in newer versions.  Which would explain why one machine complains about it (older version) and another one doesn't (newer version).